# Python input a fruit in the list and count how many words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So lets say I have a list like this

```
fruit = ['strawberry', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'cherry']
```

I want the user to input a name of the fruit in the list and count how many words the inputed fruit has. something like this below

```
input the fruit name: orange
orange has 6 words
```

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you mean how many letters. This is a pretty basic question/operation in python. Have you tried to look for the solution first? try googling what the `len()` function does. Secondly, what's the purpose of the list? Can the user only enter fruits within the list? Can't they input for example `'grape'`?

Comment: Why does the word even have to be in the list? Just get the length of the input.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very basic question that can easily be found with very little research. The user showed no attempt on solving this on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = ['strawberry', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'cherry']
your_fruit = input("input the fruit name:")
if your_fruit in my_list:
    count = len(your_fruit)
    print(your_fruit, " has ", count, "letters")
else:
    print(your_fruit, " is not in ", my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len(string)` Function.

```py
orange_name = 'orange'
print(len(orange_name))
```